# Django 3.2 REST API : Postgressql video upload fails

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-postgresql, django-3.2

I'm attempting to upload a video of 32 MB in 2k resolution to my backend django 3.2 rest api with postgres-sql as my database engine deployed on GCP ubuntu with v2 cpus and 8 Gb memory.

My front end flutter app crashes with a buffer pool eviction error. I focussed on the frontend for the past few hours. However upon inspecting the docker-compose logs just to rule out any backend issue, I get the following just before it fails on the front end :

```
video-project-postgresql-db  | 2023-11-01 12:44:56.708 UTC [27] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 79 buffers (0.5%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=7.636 s, sync=0.007 s, total=7.654 s; sync files=48, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=301 kB, estimate=301 kB; lsn=0/21C93A0, redo lsn=0/21C9368
```

Need to understand what this means. Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you give the actual error? I'm not familiar with anything like "buffer pool eviction" in an error message from postgresql, just from mysql.

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding. The buffer pool eviction is for the frontend as a reference. The only one I See in the backend is the one in the highlighted box above.

Comment: That's not an error though is it? If it was it would say ERROR. That's just a checkpoint happening.

Comment: Ok richard. I didn't know that. That is sufficient for me to troubleshoot in the front end now.